# Transfer rows with matching string from dataframes without specifying string contents in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, is it possible to pull rows from existing data frames to a new data frame based on whether the rows contain an identical string in a specific column, without specifying what that string is? EG, wherever there are rows that match in a certain column, regardless of content, to select those rows and add them to a new data frame?

An illustration:
Given the two data frames

```
    a1 <- data.frame(a = letters[1:14], b=1:14)
    a2 <- data.frame(a = letters[26:13],b=1:14)
```

they have two identical values in their second column: a1[13,1] & a2[14,1] are "m", while a1[14,1] & a2[13,1] are "n". What I'm looking for would output two data frames such as:

```
    b1 <- data.frame(a = c("a1","a2"),b = c(a1[13,1],a2[14,1]),c = c(a1[13,2],a2[14,2]))
    b2 <- data.frame(a = c("a1","a2"),b = c(a1[14,1],a2[13,1]),c = c(a1[14,2],a2[13,2]))
```

so that, in column a, the data frames from which the rows were pulled would be noted, and in columns b and c, the two observations from the original data frames would be reproduced.

I understand how to do this with a specified string, just not how to do it for a non-specific matching string! I apologize if this is really basic or redundant, this is extremely new to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = letters[1:14], b=1:14, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
a2 <- data.frame(a = letters[26:13],b=1:14, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Matching entries in column "a" from dataframes a1 and b2
m <- intersect(a1$a, a2$a);

# Return list of dataframes for every matching element
ret <- lapply(m, function(x) 
    rbind.data.frame(
        c(src = "a1", a1[which(a1$a == x), ]),
        c(src = "a2", a2[which(a2$a == x), ])))
names(ret) <- c("b1", "b2")
ret

#$b1
#  src a  b
#1  a1 m 13
#2  a2 m 14
#
#$b2
#  src a  b
#1  a1 n 14
#2  a2 n 13
```

Mind you: I can't think of a situation where this would be a useful thing to do. Perhaps/probably I'm not getting the full picture. Or maybe you have to rethink your approach?

Also note that you'd have to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if you want `b1` and `b2` to show the actual matching character (rather than the factor level). In your example above, the second column of `b1` and `b2` will give you the factor level. Again, not sure what you're actually after.